# Godement product of lax 2-natural transformations

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

> Which of the two obvious choices for the Godement product of lax $2$-natural transformations is ‘correct’?

Specifically, recall that for natural categories, functors and natural transformations as below

[image]

we define the Godement product of natural transformations to be the natural transformation

[image]

$$(\beta\star\alpha)_X = G'(\alpha_X)\circ\beta_{F(X)}=\beta_{F'(X)}\circ G(\alpha_X).$$

with equality for the two choices following from the naturality square for $\beta$ at $\alpha_X$

[image]

Stepping up to dimension $2$, the final diagram above doesn't commute unless we work with strict $2$-natural transformations. For pseudonatural transformations we have a $2$-cell isomorphism filling that square so both choices are isomorphic, but if we drop to a lax $2$-dimensional setting we only have a (not necessarily invertible) $2$-cell filling that square.

Depending on the conventions we choose for our lax $2$-natural transformations the arrow points in one direction or the other, and there are corresponding notions of modification composition for both; which choice is correct for a given orientation? Is there any meaningful difference? More precisely,

> If we construct lax $2$-functor lax $2$-categories with lax $2$-natural transformations between lax $2$-categories using the two differing choices above, are they equivalent?

They obviously are in the pseudo-case, but I can't seem to find a reference on $2$-category theory that discusses the fully lax case; this makes sense in light of strictification theorems, but I'd like to explore the fully lax case as a microcosm of lax-vs-strict notions in higher dimensions where strictification is less straightforward. Looking through [Donaldson and Yau's](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06055) excellent book and the references therein doesn't appear to yield anything, but it's very possible I just missed it. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: A small comment: a precise version of "They obviously are in the pseudo-case" is given in [11.7.9 of Donaldson–Yau](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.06055.pdf#page=395) (the link goes directly to page 395, where 11.7.9 appears). There, they mention that the two compositions for _strong_ transformations give rise to two different tricategories of bicategories which in turn turn out to be triequivalent. (I'm not sure how things work out in the fully lax scenario though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there *is* a correct "convention to choose" for our lax 2-natural transformations.  A lax transformation $\alpha : F\Rightarrow F'$ has components $F'(g) \circ \alpha_A \to \alpha_B \circ F(g)$ for any morphism $g:A\to B$, and therefore the 2-cell in your square goes from bottom-left to top-right.  If you want the 2-cell to go in the other direction, you should speak of an *oplax* transformation.  It's true that this is only a convention, but it's the universally used convention, so we should stick to it and not create confusion.

But as for the actual question, neither of the choices is "correct".  In particular, neither choice can be taken as "the" composite and yield a tricategory containing lax transformations.  The correct 3-dimensional structure containing lax transformations doesn't *have* a basic notion of Godement-style horizontal composite of two 2-cells; it just has whiskerings of 2-cells by 1-cells, and a 3-cell mediating the corresponding square for the two ways to "compose" a pair of 2-cells horizontally by first whiskering and then composing vertically.

In the case of strict 2-categories and strict 2-functors (and lax transformations), this structure can be defined as a category enriched over 2-Cat with the lax version of the Gray tensor product (the tensor product that is left adjoint to the internal-hom on 2-Cat consisting of 2-functors and lax transformations).  In the weak case, it should be a suitable weakening of that; I don't know if it's been written down.

Comment: Thank you; do your comments about whiskering and composing vs. Godement-ing apply at the $2$-dimensional level for lax $2$-functor lax $2$-categories?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  First of all I don't know what a "lax 2-category" is.  Second when talking about any kind of "2-functor 2-category" I would normally understand a 2-category $[C,D]$ whose objects are some kind of 2-functor from $C$ to $D$ and whose morphisms are some kind of transformation between them, but the whole question of whiskering vs Godement doesn't appear until you have *three* 2-categories as in your question.

Comment: In other words, a "2-functor 2-category" to me is a hom-2-category of the sort of 3-dimensional structures I mentioned in my question, and the issue doesn't appear when discussing only one of them.

Comment: I’m probably just confused, I’ll straighten out my thoughts and try to clarify in the next few days (thank you for the patience).